# Java factory method caching

Tags: java, design-patterns, concurrency

I have to develop something like a game of life. For that, I have a class called `CellPosition` that has `x` and `y` fields. In order to efficiently use memory, I would like to use some kind of factory method.

`CellPosition.at(int x, int y)` which would return an instance of `CellPosition`. I would like though to cache the objects that have the same `x, y` pair. I though of a `List` or a `HashMap`, but I cannot figure out what to use as a key. A concatenation of `x` and `y` in a string is doubtingly a good idea.

On the other hand, is it a good idea to just create an object each time and just redefine the `equals()` method to compare the objects and throw away any caching?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't mind using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), just:

1. Make `CellPosition` instances immutable, then
2. Use an [`Interner<CellPosition>`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Interner.html) (obtained from [`Interners`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Interners.html)), then
3. Move on to solving real problems.

Something like this:

```
class CellPosition
{
    private static final Interner<CellPosition> CACHE = Interners.newStrongInterner();
    // or .newWeakInterner(), to allow instances to be garbage collected

    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    private CellPosition(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = x;
    }

    public int x() { return x; }
    public int y() { return y; }

    public static CellPosition at(int x, int y)
    {
        return CACHE.intern(new CellPosition(x, y));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {/* TODO */}

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {/* TODO */}
}
```

You could also use a Guava [`Cache`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html) instead of an `Interner`, but there's not much point since you'd have to construct an int-pair key for the cache — which you're doing anyway for the interner, in fewer LoC.

Comment: Thank you, that would be my fallback if I don't find any vanilla solution.

Comment: You can do exactly the same thing with vanilla Java, but I don't see a compelling reason to reinvent the wheel here. Besides Guava is a fantastic library - once you start using it, you'll love it.

Answer (score 1):

I think caching these objects is not necessary, specially if they're very small as you seem to imply. What you can do at first is exactly what you described, have `CellPosition` as a *value object*, which is immutable; and properly implement `equals` and `hashCode`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AOP and [`@Cacheable`](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aspects/apidocs-0.7.7/com/jcabi/aspects/Cacheable.html) annotation from [jcabi-aspects](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aspects/):

```
class CellPosition {
  @Cacheable(forever = true)
  public static CellPosition at(int x, int y) {
    // instantiate and return
  }
}
```