# Caching the result of a method in Java

Tags: java, caching

I have this method that loads a lot of data from the database:

```
private List<Something> loadFromDb() {
    // Some loading which can take a lot of time
}
```

I am looking for a ***simple*** way to cache the results for some fixed time (2 minutes for example). I do not need to intercept the method invocation itself, just to cache the *returned data*. I can write another method that does the caching if necessary.

I don't want to:

- Use [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) compile time weaving like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14670421/1047448) - it requires changes in the build
- Use `@Cacheable` in Spring. I have to define a cache for each cacheable method

Is there a library which can simplify this task, or should I do something else? An example use of such library would be

```
private List<Something> loadFromDbCached() {
    // In Java 8, 'this::loadFromDb' would be possible instead of a String
    return SimpleCaching.cache(this, "loadFromDb", 2, MINUTES).call();
}
```

I am looking for a library that does that, managing the cache is more trouble than it seems, especially if you have concurrent access

Comment: Simplest would be using a HashMap with a timer that releases it every 2 minutes.

Comment: @arynaq That's hardly the simplest :) You can go simpler by storing the last update, because you do not need to clear unless there's another request.

Comment: @arynaq take a look at Google Guava's LoadingCache. That does this for you. Implementing such functionality is far from simple.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use Guava's [Suppliers.memoizeWithExpiration(Supplier delegate, long duration, TimeUnit unit)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.html#memoizeWithExpiration%28com.google.common.base.Supplier,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29):

```
private final Supplier<List<Something>> cache =
    Suppliers.memoizeWithExpiration(new Supplier<List<Something>>() {
        public List<Something> get() {
            return loadFromDb();
        }
    }, 2, MINUTES);

private List<Something> loadFromDbCached() {
    return cache.get();
}
```

Comment: This is a lot like what I need, it's just too verbose. I'll try to find (or write) a implementation of Supplier which takes a method (or just a method name).

Comment: Yes, in Java <8, there is no type-safe way of writing this more concisely. I recommend using another JVM language. ;)

Comment: what about java-8 `Supplier` and caching?

Answer (score 8):

Check [Guava Cache Builder](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained). It may be useful.

Comment: +1, this is a fantastic way of caching, with expiry and all

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`@Cacheable`](http://aspects.jcabi.com/annotation-cacheable.html) annotation from [jcabi-aspects](http://aspects.jcabi.com/):

```
public class Resource {
  @Cacheable(lifetime = 5, unit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  public String load(URL url) {
    return url.openConnection().getContent();
  }
}
```

The result of `load()` will be cached for five seconds.